# Is it possible to use a variable to reference a column in an Oracle trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle9i

I have a table in a legacy Oracle 9 database. I'm trying to write a trigger that, given an update to a row in that table, will loop through table columns, and for each column C check whether `:old[C] = :new[C]`.

Is it possible to reference the column data for `:old` and `:new` in this way, using some variable for the column name whose data we want to see?

Comment: Oracle 9 is long gone and now it is Oracle 19c. What stops you from upgrading it ?

Comment: Legacy infrastructure that we're trying to move the client off, and this trigger is a support mechanism in that process of moving the client off it. I'm well aware that Oracle 9 is in the dust, but raise that with my client's engineering department and see how far it gets you.....

Comment: To answer your question, it is not clear. Kindly put some code that you tried. And explain what exactly is it that you want.

Comment: @Ranagal my question is very clear. Is it possible to use the syntax `:old[C]` and `:new[C]` to reference a column on the bound variables `:old` and `:new`, where `C` is a variable from (for example) `SELECT column_name FROM User_Tab_Columns WHERE Upper(Table_Name) = 'ACDB_AC_TYPES';`

Answer (score 0):

Frist you cant find all table columns with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Secondly in order to loop throught thoses columns an test the old and new values you can compose a query with this command: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('<my query>');` like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [...]
    l_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DUAL WHERE '||:old.C||' = '||:new.C INTO l_cnt;
END;
```

---

UPDATE 1:

You can also do it "by hand" and test each column manually like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE OF [...]
BEGIN
    IF :old.A != :new.A THEN
        --field A has changed
    ELSIF :old.B != :new.B THEN
        --field B has changed
    ELSIF :old.C != :new.C THEN
        --field C has changed
--continue with other fields
    END IF;
END;
```

---

EDIT : changed ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to USER_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: You need to filter `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` on the owner column too otherwise you will find you are picking up columns from other tables of the same name in different schemas.

Comment: Right, I forgot about his one. Or use `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi @SuperPoney, thanks for your reply. Could you provide some more context for the `execute immediate` query you mention? How you used it inside the for loop? I've written a for loop around it, but the first instance of `[C]` - i.e. `:old[C]` is giving me a syntax error with an unexpected token [

Comment: I've updated my answer and changed the `:old[C]` to the correct syntax `:old.C`. The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`statement let you execute queries from a string. Maybe I've misunderstood your request. If you want to test each column old and new value you need to kwon their datatype in order to compare them (for this you need to check in the USER_TAB_COLUMNS). The simpliest way is to check field by field (let assume your table does not have hundred of columns). Please check my updated answer.